# how to use jquery != with condtional || operator

Tags: jquery

Sorry, as this is same type question I asked today. But as the earlier question got bigger and confusing, I have to ask this question again separately.
I have following code in my body section:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select id="fruits" name="fruits">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Mango</option>
<option>Orange</option>
</select>
<select id="color" name="color">
<option>Red</option>
<option>Green</option>
<option>Yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="result" value="" />
```

What I want to do, If a user select Apple from fruits and change color from second drop down menu, "Right Choice" will be appeared in #result input. On the other hand, if a user selects Mango or Orange from fruits and change color option, value will be cleared from #result input. So the jquery code will be like this:

```
$("#color").change(function() {
if($("#fruits").val()!="Mango" || $("#fruits").val()!="Orange"){
  $("#result").val(""); 
}else{
  $("#result").val("Right Choice"); 
}
});
```

But it is not working. Changing of any fruits, clearing the value from #result input. But if I use only one condition in if statement, it is working well.

```
$("#color").change(function() {
if($("#fruits").val()!="Mango"){
  $("#result").val(""); 
}else{
  $("#result").val("Right Choice"); 
}
});
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  if(($("#fruits").val()!="Mango") && ($("#fruits").val()!="Orange")){
  $("#result").val(""); 
} else{
  $("#result").val("Right Choice"); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#fruits").val()!="Mango" || $("#fruits").val()!="Orange"){
```

means the case if **TRUE** if the value is either NOT Mango or NOT Orange. In your case, you should replace `||` with `&&` so that if user selects Mango or Orange, it will prompt `Right Choice`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fruit to not be mango and orange you can use &&(AND) instead of OR.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($("#fruits").val()!="Mango" || $("#fruits").val()!="Orange"){
```

To

```
if( !($("#fruits").val()=="Mango" || $("#fruits").val()=="Orange")){
```